# Positioning modal under specific button in Bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an AngularJs 1.0.7 website. In a page I have a list of filter buttons. I´m opening a modal on each button click. But I would like to position the modal just under the button (as a dropdown). How can I do it?

**HTML**

```
<div class="row-fluid custom-row-margin-10">
    <div class="span12">        
        <ul class="unstyled inline">    
            <li class="filter-title">{{'FILTER_BY' | translate}}</li>       
            <li>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-filter" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#filter-boat-type">
                    {{'BOAT_TYPE' | translate}}
                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-large" ng-class="{'btn-filter': !filters.lengthMin && !filters.lengthMax, 'btn-filter-selected': filters.lengthMin || filters.lengthMax}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#filter-length">
                    <span ng-hide="filters.lengthMin || filters.lengthMax">{{'LENGTH' | translate}}</span>
                    <span ng-show="filters.lengthMin || filters.lengthMax">{{'FROM_2' | translate}} {{filters.lengthMin}}m. {{'TO_2' | translate}} {{filters.lengthMax}}m.</span>
                </button>
            </li>
       </ul>
...

<!-- MODAL TYPE -->
<div id="filter-boat-type" class="modal hide fade filters-wrapper">
    <div class="row-fluid boat-filters custom-row-margin-10">
        <div class="span12">                                        
            Modal content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/I6BSKbpclDnBNunNwLt2?p=preview

**UPDATE**
I have been testing dropdown menus as suggested by the comments below. But I´m not sure if this is the right component, because I need some functionality that dropdowns do not provide by default:
1. The dropdowns are filters, so there are forms inside. User needs to click inside the form elements preventing to close the dropdown.
2. This is not 100% mandatory, but I would like to disable all background and put it in another color (as modals).

So, not sure, if it´s better to use a modal and style it to position it below the buttons or the dropdown and update the functionality to prevent close it. From the functional point of view (forgetting the design), I think modals matches better than a dropdown menu.

So, unless It´s clear dropdowns should be used, I´m back with the modal approach. I have updated the plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/I6BSKbpclDnBNunNwLt2?p=preview
But still have an issue. When user clicks on first filter, the modal opens, but the second filter button moves to the right. I don´t want this. I think this can be achieved with css but not too skilled.

Comment: may be instead of using "modal" plugin of bootstrap,  to use "dropdownmenu" will better fit your scenario (http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#dropdowns)?

Comment: But can I put any content inside dropdown menus? Or just lists?

Comment: Rober you can for sure put your content instead of a list :)

Comment: Please see my update @happyZZR1400

Comment: How about use  ui-bootstrap(lib for displaying bootstrap plugins with angular) https://plnkr.co/edit/pomHWf?p=info?

Comment: I´m already using UI-Boostrap 0.6.0. I have tried and the dropdown is working. However, still don´t know how to prevent close the dropdown on click. My version is pretty old and not maintained anymore. I don´t even find any doc.